# Node.js + GraphQL + MongoDB + Flutter App on Heroku crashing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, graphql

I am fairly new to programming and I am learning node.js, so this maybe something very stupid that I just can't seem to spot.

I tried to bring back to life the app that I've wrote about a year ago. The app worked at a time.
However, I can't get it running now. I'd appreciate any tips and guidance.

What I did:

1. I updated all the dependencies
2. I made sure that I can connect to the same MongoDB using same creds via Atlas
3. I whitelisted the IP
4. Heroku port is assigned via a variable, just as all other DB configurations  Builds on Heroku are successful
5. I didn't make any changes into the graphql.
6. Server is running via nodemon app (I get a console message 'Listening for requests on my awesome port').
7. If I try to launch it as via node app.js - I get a Mongodb bad auth error (but I can connect to the same DB via Atlas using same creds).
8. When I launch the app using the simulator (again used to work fine) I get the error messages saying 'graphql errors'.

The Heroku logs tail:

```
2023-03-31T14:37:40.596469+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js',
2023-03-31T14:37:40.596469+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/index.js',
2023-03-31T14:37:40.596469+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js',
2023-03-31T14:37:40.596469+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js'
2023-03-31T14:37:40.596469+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2023-03-31T14:37:40.596470+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-03-31T14:37:40.596488+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-31T14:37:40.596489+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.15.0
2023-03-31T14:37:40.741434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-03-31T14:37:40.791956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-03-31T15:09:12.406470+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `heroku run` by user maria@gmail.com
2023-03-31T15:09:21.024287+00:00 heroku[run.6451]: State changed from starting to up
2023-03-31T15:09:21.308441+00:00 heroku[run.6451]: Awaiting client
2023-03-31T15:09:21.323448+00:00 heroku[run.6451]: Starting process with command `heroku run`
2023-03-31T15:09:25.221601+00:00 heroku[run.6451]: Process exited with status 127
2023-03-31T15:09:25.270679+00:00 heroku[run.6451]: State changed from up to complete
2023-03-31T15:12:48.660927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-03-31T15:12:59.580186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055064+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055105+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055105+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055105+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055106+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../polyfills/symbols.js'
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055106+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055106+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/error/GraphQLError.js
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055107+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055107+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055107+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055107+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/index.js
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055108+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055108+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055108+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055109+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055109+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055109+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055110+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/graphql/error/GraphQLError.js:13:16)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055110+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055110+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055110+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055111+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055111+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055112+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055112+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055112+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/error/GraphQLError.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055113+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055113+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055113+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055113+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/index.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055114+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055114+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js'
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055114+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055114+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055146+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-31T15:13:02.055146+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.15.0
2023-03-31T15:13:02.262772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-03-31T15:13:02.328273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-03-31T15:13:02.332633+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-03-31T15:13:02.864200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/graphql" host=mvp-timelyst.herokuapp.com request_id=1bf6cc3e-57ba-4f40-b034-bd563f375601 fwd="66.30.85.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-31T15:13:07.368943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957341+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957359+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957359+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957360+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957360+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../polyfills/symbols.js'
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957361+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957361+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/error/GraphQLError.js
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957361+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957361+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957362+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957362+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/graphql/index.js
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957362+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957363+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957365+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957365+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957366+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957366+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957368+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/graphql/error/GraphQLError.js:13:16)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957370+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957372+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957372+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/error/GraphQLError.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957372+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957373+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957373+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957373+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/graphql/index.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957373+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js',
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957374+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js'
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957374+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957374+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957379+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-31T15:13:08.957379+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.15.0
2023-03-31T15:13:09.124857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-03-31T15:13:09.166154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-03-31T15:13:09.996172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mvp-timelyst.herokuapp.com request_id=3af98090-0a76-4040-9e4c-5717f6600445 fwd="66.30.85.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-31T15:20:19.814264+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/graphql" host=mvp-timelyst.herokuapp.com request_id=96499f86-dbca-4990-bf82-a7a12e480b51 fwd="66.30.85.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-31T15:20:19.947369+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mvp-timelyst.herokuapp.com request_id=69d9dc29-3b2e-42a2-887e-e11f98c0370b fwd="66.30.85.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am a bit at loss.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused due to incorrect processing of the env variables

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).